# how can i change the button icon in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter

i am creating a gui in tkinter in which i have a button. and i don't want a simple button i want an icon instead of a button and when i click on a button its icon should be change.
so that i can perform start() and stop() function with a same button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = tk.Tk()
def change_i():
        if sound_btn[image] == icon:
            #start_recording()

            sound_btn.config(image=icon2)
        else:
            #stop_recording()

            sound_btn.config(image=icon)

icon = PhotoImage(file='dh.png')
icon2 = PhotoImage(file='stop.png')

sound_btn = tk.Button(frame, image=icon, width=70,height=60,relief=FLAT ,command=change_i )
sound_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does `sound_btn.config(image=icon2)` and `sound_btn.config(image=icon)` work? I presume you meant to pass the variables rather than a string...

Comment: @EdWard no it doesn't work. code updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = tk.Tk()
def change_i():
    if sound_btn.image == icon:
        #start_recording()

        sound_btn.config(image=icon2)
        sound_btn.image = icon2
    else:
        #stop_recording()

        sound_btn.config(image=icon)
        sound_btn.image = icon

icon = PhotoImage(file='dh.png')
icon2 = PhotoImage(file='stop.png')

sound_btn = tk.Button(root, image=icon, width=70,height=60,relief=FLAT ,command=change_i )
sound_btn.image = icon
sound_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Edit:

This answer works by saving the current image in the `image` attribute of `sound_btn`, and compares that each time the button is clicked. `sound_btn['image']` returns the "image id" of the current image, not a reference to it.

Comment: This answer would be better if you added a sentence or two explaining what you did differently. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.